# How use shortcode's callback function directly which uses opening and closing tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code:

```
<?php
  $my_linkdownload = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'linkdownload', true);
  if( ! empty( $my_linkdownload ) ) {
echo do_shortcode('[pms-restrict subscription_plans="8"] <a href="' . $my_linkdownload . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://koran.pustakakoran.com/img/etc/pdf.png"> </a>[/pms-restrict]');
}
?>
```

How I change the code to shortcode's callback function directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
 <?php
    add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'shortcode_callback');

function shortcode_callback(){
      $my_linkdownload = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'linkdownload', true);
      if( ! empty( $my_linkdownload ) ) {
           echo do_shortcode('[pms-restrict subscription_plans="8"] <a href="' . $my_linkdownload . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://koran.pustakakoran.com/img/etc/pdf.png"> </a>[/pms-restrict]');
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: I have tried your add code, but in frontend do not show. Any else idea?

Comment: Have you getting value from $my_linkdownload?

Comment: Can you use <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content',' [pms-restrict] ');?>